# await TaskEx.Delay

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am playing with HttpListener and Async CTP

```
class HttpServer : IDisposable
{
    HttpListener listener;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public void Start()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:1288/test/");
        listener.Start();

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Listen();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    int counter = 0;

    private async void Listen()
    {
        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsyncTask(); // my extension method with TaskCompletionSource and BeginGetContext
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected " + ++counter);

            // simulate long network i/o
            await TaskEx.Delay(5000, cts.Token);

            Console.WriteLine("Response " + counter);
            // send response
        }

        listener.Close();
    }
}
```

I expected the following output when 3 clients connect at the same time

```
Client connected 1
Client connected 2
Client connected 3
<5000ms pause>
Response 1
Response 2
Response 3
```

Instead I get

```
Client connected 1
<5000ms pause>
Response 1
Client connected 2
<5000ms pause>
Response 2
Client connected 3
<5000ms pause>
Response 3
```

If I use continuation it works like I expected

```
int c = counter;
TaskEx.Delay(5000, cts.Token).ContinueWith(t => {
    Console.WriteLine("Response " + c);
    // send response
});
```

I was under the impression that `await TaskEx.Delay` returns immediately (and will go to `while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)`) and the remainder of the while block will be the continuation after 5000ms. So it should be the same as my code with `.ContinueWith`, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TaskEx.Delay will return a task immediately, but you're *awaiting* that task before you call `listener.GetContextAsyncTask()` again. The *caller* (`Start`) will continue as soon as you hit the first `await` statement which isn't already completed, but *within* the `Listen` method, it has the appearance of synchronous code - that's the *point* of `await`.

It's not "the remainder of the block" lexically that occurs when the continuation fires - it's "the remainder of the execution of the method". In other words, the method effectively "pauses" at the `await`, but allows the *caller* to proceed.

Comment: Instinctually await'ing the rest of the block actually makes sense. Is it something that makes technical sense too?

Comment: @Overflow: Imagine the block is a loop, and you've got an await in the middle... when you get to the end of the block, you'll go back to *before* the await expression. Does that help answer your question? I'm not sure I follow...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to accomplish what I wanted to do (i.e. use `await` instead of `.ContinueWith` and delegates):

```
private async void Listen()
{
    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsyncTask();
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected " + ++counter);

        ProcessRequest(context, counter);
    }

    listener.Close();
}

private async void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context, int c)
{
    await TaskEx.Delay(5000, cts.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("Response " + c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works because of Jon's point above being 'the remainder of the execution of the method'